# NameError: global name 'reverse' is not defined

Tags: python

New to python.... really confused with this weird error....
I don't think I'm doing anything wrong, am I?

main.py

```
from methods import Reverse

def main ():

    b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,8,9,1,212,312,31,23,123455435,56,56,123]
    a = "llaa"

    thing = Reverse()
    print thing.reverse(a)


main()
```

methods.py

```
class Reverse():

  def __init__(self):
    print "initialized reverse"

  def reverse(self,var):
    if var == "":
      return var
    else: 
      print var[-1] + reverse(var[:-1])
```

I'm trying to do a recursive call with reverse....
Please kindly help. Thanks!

Comment: Whoever taught you that `Reverse` should be a class needs to be sued for educational malpractice.

Comment: I rolled back your edit.  If you think the problem is solved, it should be solved in one of the answers below (green checkmark) -- don't put the answer in the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike some other languages where `this` is implied, Python requires you to explicitly say `self` whenever using instance methods or variables so in `Reverse` you need to explicitly say

```
self.reverse(var[:-1])
```

Of course `reverse` does not return anything so you need to change it to

```
return var[-1] + self.reverse(var[:-1])
```

Comment: actually it should be return var[-1] + self.reverse(var[:-1])

Comment: but can we do a print? I thought we can put str() around it.. :/

Comment: `str()` is used to convert something to the string type. I am not sure what you mean by doing a print. `main` prints it right?

Comment: It's much more complicated to do print in the recursive function, and it is much better divide the code that does the reversing from the code that does the output.

Answer (score 4):

In your class `Reverse`, `reverse` is a method, so you need to call it as a method:

```
print var[-1] + self.reverse(var[:-1])
```

Note the `self`.

Comment: Thanks :) 

Now.. I'm getting this `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects`